# How to understand וּמִמֶּ֖גֶד גֶּ֥רֶשׁ יְרָחִֽים - "the bounteous crop of the moons" and Rashi on Devorim 33 (14)

Tags: rashi, fruits, moon, parashat-vezot-habracha

[Devorim 33 (14)](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.33.14?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en) says

> וּמִמֶּ֖גֶד תְּבוּאֹ֣ת שָׁ֑מֶשׁ וּמִמֶּ֖גֶד גֶּ֥רֶשׁ יְרָחִֽים׃
>
> With the bounteous yield of the sun, And the bounteous crop of the
> moons;

Rashi says

> גרש ירחים [AND BY] THE PRECIOUS THINGS PUT THINGS FORTH BY THE MOON —
> there are some fruits which the moon brings to maturity, these are
> cucumbers and melons (Sifrei Devarim 353:3). — Another explanation of
> גרש ירחים: this refers to fruits which the earth puts out and produces
> from month to month (cf. Onkelos).

Rashi's peshotim are difficult to understand.

1] The moon reflects light from the sun. So it seems unlikely that only the moon (and not the sun) will ripen  cucumbers and melons.

2] The 2nd pshat seems to suggest that the earth produces different produce each Rosh Chodesh as Onkelos says,
וְעָבְדָא מִגְדָּנִין וַעֲלָלָן מִיבוּל שִׁמְשָׁא וְעָבְדָא מִגְדָּנִין מֵרֵישׁ יְרַח בִּירַח:

So, two linked questions [1] What does the possuk mean and [2] can Rashi's peshotim be explained better?

Comment: I understood it as there being plants that grow better at night. The light from the moon is less intense, etc.

Comment: @Harel13 Please explain how plants grow better **from the light of the moon**. If light helps growth, the sun is better; if light doesn't help, growth would be better in the absence of the light of the moon.

Comment: Not being an expert biologist, I can only suggest that for some plants the sun's light may be too intense. The moon's light is weaker, of course. Check this out: https://www.google.com/search?q=plants%20that%20grow%20with%20moonlight&start=0 (and Rashi had a vineyard, so I think he's pretty trustworthy on general knowledge about plants)

Answer (score 1):

1] I don't think Rashi means that the moon exclusively ripens those fruits, just that it contributes.

2]The second pshat implies that there are some crops that grow in a thirty day cycle, so presumably if they were planted on Rosh Chodesh they would ripen around the next Rosh Chodesh. An example would be אספסתא, which [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.28b.9?lang=he&with=Rashi&lang2=he) to Maseches Bava Basra says ripens after thirty days.